# Calling a VS2010 C++ dll from VB in Visual Studio 6

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, boost, visual-c++-6

It's my first question in Stack Overflow and it goes like this: 
 I'm implementing some algorithms in C++, for a company that will use them as a DLL from Visual Basic in Visual Studio 6 (service pack 6). All the above (building as DLL, ability to call from VB, VS6) are mandatory and not something I can change. 
 My approach so far (since I was asked to deliver code "compilable" in VC6) was to make the original implementation in VS2010 (with C++98 code standards), port and compile the code as a DLL in VC6, make function wrappers, and finally make "caller functions" in VB, accessing the DLL code. If I could use Boost::Geometry (eg make a wrapper function that performs a polygon union without exposing the template mechanism) my life would be much much better, but I can't compile it in VC6 so here is what I'm asking: **Could a C++ DLL built in VS2010, be called from Visual Studio 6? Are there any tips or pitfalls?** I simply want to use some newly made, fully tested, trustworthy C++ goodies as independent libraries that the recipient won't have the need to debug (at least I don't think they are planning to debug Boost).

Comment: There's a company still developing new code with Visual Studio 6?!?

Comment: it's a very lightweight IDE...

Comment: In a nutshell, it's doable, but you'll need to export a C-style interface

Comment: Just looking at the screen of VC6 one gets depressed but JosephH has a point. @PeskyGnat So I must have been doing something wrong in my recent attempts, thanks for removing the uncertainty, it allows me to work more focused

Comment: The bolded question makes little sense, VS6 doesn't call DLLs.  I imagine they are asking you to write a COM server that they can use from a VB6 program.  That's possible, COM hides implementation so VS versions don't matter.  But they seem to want code that *compiles* in VS6.  So forget everything that was created in the past 13 years, it isn't likely to compile.  You'd better go shopping for a VS6 license (very hard to find) and charge them an arm and a leg.

Comment: I'm assuming you just want to wrap some recent code that may only compile on recent compilers into something more 'lagacier' apps could use, not something useable from the VB6 IDE itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating an ActiveX component using ATL so that you can simply add them as references in VB6